# Updating column with sequence numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table for patients and this table has an empty column (varying character) and I want to fill it with sequence numbers and the sequence should start from 1 and end with the number of rows

I also have an existing column that takes holds the date when the row was created, I want the numbers that will be filled in the empty column to be ordered by giving 1 to the oldest date and so on.

Comment: Please tag a database you use. Cheers. Also, show some example data of the table before and after the updating...

Comment: what is you dbms?

Comment: @MuntherYousef . . . Do you have a primary key in the table?

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `ROW_NUMBER` here, at the time you query, rather than updating your table:

```
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_col DESC) rn
FROM yourTable;
```

The reason for *not* attempting an update here is that as soon as new data gets inserted into the table, you might be forced to run the update again, and that could get messy after a while.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this for update:

Let's say your table is called **test** and columns are **id**(*the one that is empty*) and d**ate_col**(*the column with date when the row was created*).

And update your table with this statement:

```
update test t1
set id = t2.row_num
from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date_col desc) row_num, date_col 
       from test) t2
where t1.date_col = t2.date_col;
```

Then to prepare everything for the future inserts I would create a function and a trigger. Function returns the next number that needs to be inserted in the id column and a trigger makes sure that that number will be inserted every next time the insert is made.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sequence_test_up()
 RETURNS "trigger" AS
 $BODY$
 BEGIN
   New.id:= (select max(id)+1 from test);
   Return NEW;
 END;
 $BODY$
 LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

CREATE TRIGGER Test_Tr
 BEFORE INSERT
 ON test
 FOR EACH ROW
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE sequence_test_up();
```

And then the next insert would insert ID with the value of the next number in line.

[Here is the DEMO with step by step example.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=76b3dfff30b59eac411da0d72594a429)

Comment: Hi, @MuntherYousef, I hope this answer helps you but please do give a feedback to people who helped you. They spend their time t owrite some code for you. You can comment(tell people what is wrong if something is...) and accept the answer if it is correct. Also when you will have 15 points (now you have 11) you will be able to vote up the answer that helepd you but maybe they are not 100% correct(yo then you vote up that answer and in a comment you say what is not correct...)